# How to create a Retrofit post from Android Studio App to asp.net api Controller?

Tags: android, asp.net, retrofit

I want to sent my Testclass to my Webervice as a Json.
Thererfor I use Retrofit

```
 send(){
    Retrofit r = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://hostname:77777")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

    UserApi service = r.create(UserApi.class);

service.sendData(new Test());
}

public interface UserApi{
@PUT("/api/values")
Call<Object> sendData(@Body Test test);
}
```

here is my test class in java :

```
public class Test {
    public String name = "name";
    public String street = "simple";
}
```

here in c#

```
public class Test

{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String street { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller methode:

```
// POST api/values

public void Post([FromBody]Test value)
{
}

// PUT api/values/5
public String Put(string id, [FromBody]Test value)
{}
```

But this is not working. The servermethodes don´t get hit and I get not error warning or exeption of some sort.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?